# Generic way to handle DuplicateBeanException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Team, I am working on an Spring boot application which uses lot of other third party libraries.
All those libraries are built on top of spring core.
The common issue that usually comes is `DuplicateBeanException`.
Let's say if the bean-name is same from different libraries, spring throws error while trying to start the server. As I do not have control over third party jars. I have to rename the beans in my application: below is the code snippet I wrote to handle this scenario. But this is not an efficient solution as in future there can be again some duplicate beans. How can I solve it in a generic way so that when ever any duplicate beans come, my application can handle and initialize those beans.

My code to handle duplicate bean :

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalBeanConfiguration {
   @Bean(employeeLib1)    
   public Employee getEmployee() {
          return new Employee();
   }

   @Bean(employeeLib2)    
   public com.another.library.Employee getEmployee() {
          return new com.another.library.Employee();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you configure where to scan the beans from the external libraries by `@ComponentScan` , you can specify a `BeanNameGenerator` for how the name of the detected beans are defined.

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo.lib1" , "com.foo.lib2"}, nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class ExternalBeanConfiguration {
    
}
```

The `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` is exactly for solving your problem which is mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html) as :

> Favor this bean naming strategy over {@code
> AnnotationBeanNameGenerator} if you run into naming conflicts due to
> multiple autodetected components having the same non-qualified class
> name (i.e., classes with identical names but residing in different
> packages)

It will name the bean as the fully qualified class name as the default bean name such that even if different packages has a same class name , it will still have different bean name.